# Robot Framework - Comparing 2 string with version information (x.x.x.x)

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm making test scenario for a project and facing one problem, please help if you have time.

I have 2 string now:

> ${cr_ver} = 4.5.5
>
> ${tobe_upgr_ver} = 7.0.0

Now I want to compare them, to make like: if ${cr_ver} < ${tobe_upgr_ver}, then test stop.

Please kindly support. :)

Much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can benefit from how python compares string:

```
${cr_ver}    Set Variable    4.5.5
${tobe_upgr_ver}    Set Variable    7.0.0
Pass Execution If    '${cr_ver}' < '${tobe_upgr_ver}'    tobe_upgr_ver is greater than cr_ver, pass the test
Log    cr_ver is greater than tobe_upgr_ver so let's continue the test
```

Comment: It will fail in cases like these: "9.1" < "10.0" or "1.9" < "1.10"